# Django Admin stopped working - 'module' object is not iterable

Tags: django, admin

I'm getting started with Django. I can't get the admin to work (it used to work, I'm not sure what update made it break...).

As soon as I register a model in the admin, the website crashes with this error on any URL:

```
'module' object is not iterable
```

In the trace it happens to bug on this:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in register
        for model in model_or_iterable: 

admin_class 
<class 'django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin'>
options 
{}
model_or_iterable   
<module 'model.Branch' from '...../farmpower/src/model/Branch.pyc'>
self    
<django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite object at 0x1098196d0>
```

I've tried with different models, in that example, with Branch (code in admin.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *

admin.site.register(Branch)
```

models.py:

```
import Page, Promotion, Branch, Contact
```

Branch.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
```

[...]

```
class Meta:
    app_label = "model"
    db_table  = "cms_branch"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things in your code that are not very neat. One of them might lead to the error you're seeing, though I don't know which one of 'em is it.

- You use relative imports (`from models import ...`). It is more robust do do an absolute import like `from yourapp.models import ...`).
- You use a "star import": `from models import *`. You don't really know what you're importing exactly in the file where you're doing this. Also automatic code checkers (like [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes)) cannot check whether you're missing imports anymore.
- You mention `models.yml` as the filename. That's not a `.py` extension, so python doesn't do a thing with that one.
- The app name you set in the `Meta` on your models is `model`. Note that "models" and "model" are quite django-internal names. So having an app called "model" with a "models.py" could easily go wrong. Why is the app not `yourapp` or something like that?

Here are some ways in which it could go wrong:

Star import: perhaps you've imported a different `admin` in `models.py`? Which overwrites, through the star import, the one in admin.py?

The `models.yml`: if that really is the name, what does `from models import *` return? With a non-existing `models.py`? Try to import `Branch` explicitly: `from models import Branch` and see if it fails.

App name: if your app is really called "model", a relative import `from models import *` could perhaps get you the top-level "model" module instead of the "model.models" that you mean in case you mis-type something.

Comment: Thanks, the models.yml was just a typo I made when writing this question. I'll remove all the import ... * from my code. Yes my app is called model because I wanted to put all the model files together (I'm not going to reuse any of these in future projects); I didn't have any issue with that for the fixtures and frontend...

Comment: from model.Branch import Branch

Comment: Hurray for explicit imports! They really help in finding errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's your

```
from models import *
```

it should be

```
from appName.models import className
```